# Вставка данных во временную таблицу в цикле

Tags: sql, база-данных, sybase

Есть цикл, который проверяет наличие номера строки и столбца.Если не находит - вставляет такой номер строки/столбца во временную таблицу.
Вставка происходит очень долго 90 тыс записей больше получаса.
Помогите пож-та с оптимизацией.

```
set @j = 1;
while @j <=@max  LOOP
set @i =1;
while @i <=@max  LOOP
if not exists (select d.cod_row,d.cod_col from ltb_Matrix  d where d.cod_row =@i and d.cod_col =@j  ) then
insert into  ltb_Matrix (cod_row,cod_col,value)
VALUES(@i,@j,0)
;commit;
end if;
set @i =@i+1;
end loop;
set @j =@j+1;
end loop;
```

Comment: 1) Укажите СУБД. 2) Если ваша СУБД поддерживает `MERGE`, используйте `MERGE`. 3) Или перепишите все на `INSERT ... SELECT ...` (в селекте вычислите все строки, которых нет, и вставьте скопом).

Comment: Версия БД - Sybase IQ

Comment: это какая-то разовая задача? или нужно постоянно вставлять одни и те же данные?

Comment: раз в две недели будет идти пересчет. + даже цикл set @j = 1;
while @j <=@max  LOOP
set @i =1;
while @i <=@max  LOOP
--if not exists (select d.cod_row,d.cod_col from ltb_Matrix  d where d.cod_row =@i and d.cod_col =@j  ) then
insert into  ltb_Matrix2 (cod_row,cod_col,value)
VALUES(@i,@j,0)
;commit;
--end if;
set @i =@i+1;
end loop;
set @j =@j+1;
end loop; вставляет по 5000 за 2 минуты. 1 600 000 буду вставлять не один день(

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что у вас значения в первой и второй колонке просто увеличиваются на 1, третья колонка - всегда 0? Если да - создайте таблицу со всеми значениями, затем по необходимости через джойн добавляйте данные

Comment: Да, все правильно. только в данной бд нет возможности создать такую таблицу без цикла, cte...

Comment: Нашел способ)))генерим через цикл последовательность до значения, которое нужно.Потом через крос джоин связыем таблицу саму с собой и даее джойним по записям, при необходимости - вставляем.